# How many minutes will it be until they both meet together again

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Jess and Yara are walking laps around a park.
>
> Jess completes each lap
> in 10 minutes and then rests for 1 minute before starting the next
> lap.
>
> Yara complete each lap in 13 minutes and then rests for 2 minutes
> before starting the next lap.
>
> Jess and Yara start walking together in the same direction.
>
> How many
> minutes will it be until they both meet together again?

**My Attempt**

If we set total length of the lap is L, then Jess' speed is $\frac{L}{10}$, and Yara's speed is $\frac{L}{13}$.

The distance that Jess walked is $\frac{L}{10} \times t$, where $t$ is the time,

The distance that Yara walked is $\frac{L}{13} \times t$,

when Jess and Yara meet, that means Jess walked 1 or more laps than Yara,

If use formula, it would be $(\frac{L}{10})t + nL = (\frac{L}{13})t$, but I got stuck here.

**Notes**

This is a question from an exam paper. I have no clue how to resolve this. So any approach, whether it is working or not, or even just some thoughts or direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else?

Comment: when you are down voting a question, wouldn't be better to provide explanation or hint or something?

Comment: It's hard for someone to justify writing an answer because *they don't know what you want*. For example, if you want a totally different approach to the answer given, the answerer shouldn't have to write another answer for you. So if you could just write where the question came from, it would help others a lot.

Comment: thanks Toby. I just need an answer for this question. This is a question from an exam paper. I have no clue how to resolve this. So any approach, whether it is working or not, or even just some thoughts or direction will be highly appreciated. For those who only knows how to down vote. what will you do when you are sitting at the exam. Down voting the school ?

Comment: On this site, a downvote isn't a personal attack against you ('X is a bad person'), but it means that you haven't shown any research effort. If you could add your comment back to your question, I will gladly remove the downvote.

Comment: I suppose this is to do with algebra, if we set total length of the lap is L, then Jess' speed is L/10, and Yara's speed is L/13. the distance that Jess walked is L/10 x t, where t is the time, the distance that Yara walked is L/13 x t, when Jess and Yara meet, that means Jess walked 1 or more laps than Yara, If use formula, it would be (L/10)t + nL = (L/13)t, but I got stuck here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93216/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-ppau2004).

Answer (score 1):

We can solve the problem using modular division. Let $r$ be the radius of the park. So every lap is of length $2\pi r$. Note that Jess and Lara repeat their cycles every 11 and 15 minutes, respectively. Thus, the distance of locations of Jess and Lara from the starting point along the circle at time $t$ can be given as follows:
\begin{align}
d_{\text{Jess}} = \begin{cases}
\frac{2\pi r}{10}(t-11k), &11k<t<11k+10\\
0, &11k+10 \leq t\leq 11(k+1)\\
\end{cases}\\
d_{\text{Lara}} = \begin{cases}
\frac{2\pi r}{13}(t-15s), &15s<t<15s+13\\
0, &15s+13 \leq t\leq 15(s+1)\\
\end{cases}.
\end{align}

Now the meeting can happen when both are at starting point or when both are walking.

**Case 1: Both are way from the starting point**
\begin{align}
\frac{2\pi r}{10}(t-11k) = \frac{2\pi r}{13}(t-15k)&\implies 3t=143k-150s\\
11k<t<11k+10&\implies 15s<11k<15s+3\implies 11k \text{ mod } 15 = 1 \text{ or } 2 \\
&\implies \begin{cases}
11k \text{ mod } 15 = 1 \implies k \text{ mod } 15 = \frac{1}{11} = \frac{16}{-4}=-4=11\\
\text{OR}\\
11k \text{ mod } 15 = 2 \implies k \text{ mod } 15 = \frac{2}{11} = \frac{32}{-4}=-8=7.
\end{cases}\\
15s<t<15s+13&\implies 15s<11k<15s+3.
\end{align}
Thus, $k=7$ corresponds to the first meeting way from the starting point. Therefore, we have
\begin{equation}
15s+2=11k=77\implies s=5\implies t=143k-150s=251.
\end{equation}

**Case 2: Both are at the starting point**

We have
\begin{align}
11k+10 \leq t\leq 11(k+1)\\
15s+13 \leq t \leq 15(s+1).
\end{align}
Clearly, the smallest $t$ satisfying the above is an integer such that
\begin{align}
t \text{ mod } 11 &= 10 \text{ or } 0 \implies t = 11u+10 \text{ or } t=11u.
\\
t \text{ mod } 15 &= 13, 14 \text{ or } 0.
\end{align}
Thus, we have the following cases:
\begin{cases}
11u+10 \text{ mod } 15 = 13 \implies u = \frac{3}{11} = \frac{48}{-4} = -12 = 3\implies t=43\\
11u+10 \text{ mod } 15 = 14 \implies u = \frac{4}{11} = \frac{4}{-4} = -1=14\implies t=164\\
11u+10 \text{ mod } 15 = 0 \implies u = \frac{-10}{11} = \frac{20}{-4} = -5 = 10\implies t=120\\
\\
11u \text{ mod } 15 = 13 \implies u = \frac{13}{11} = \frac{28}{-4} = -7 = 8\implies t=88\\
11u \text{ mod } 15 = 14 \implies u = \frac{14}{11} = \frac{-16}{-4} = 4\implies t=44\\
11u \text{ mod } 15 = 0 \implies u = 15\implies t=165.\\
\end{cases}

Thus, the first meeting at the starting point happens at $t=43$.

> Hence, the final answer is $t=43$

Answer (score 0):

Let the length of the track be $1$. Then by far the easiest solution would be to graph their positions and find where they intersect. The first intersection point would be at $t = 43$.

A graph is provided on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jubnwttnru), where Jess's position is in blue and Yara's position is in green.